# Font and object edge on Yosemite

Tags: font, macos

As a lot of people here, I updated my Maverick to Yosemite. I've a MacBook Pro 2011 (early) and a Apple Display connected with a Thunderbolt. My question is: am I the only one that see the font edge not so clear? It seems a little bit blurred but enough to be annoying.

In particular the font are really annoying in Safari tab title, and system bar.

BTW: I want back old font. Now.

Comment: Check and reset your FontBook.app Check what profile is used in your ColorSync Utility.app

Comment: I detected the same problem, I feel that the font is a little blurry and hard to read. This is happening with system font and all other applications fonts like browsers (chrome & Firefox) and Adobe suit. So I think that is a general font rendering problem and is not just related to the new helvetica system font.

Comment: I seen another issue with the iBooks. I opened a PDF from my mac stored in iBook and it's blurred.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Macbook Pro 15" with Retina display and a 27" thunderbolt display. After upgrading to Yosemite the font on the macbook built-in display looks very clear, but that on the thunderbolt display looks blurry. I guess Apple did't consider the thunderbolt display users when they test the new font.